# How to show that series $\sum\frac{x}{1+n^2x}$is uniform convergent in $(t,1]$ where $t>0$ but not uniform convergent in $[0,1]$?

Tags: uniform-convergence

How to show that series $$\sum\frac{x}{1+n^2x}$$is uniform convergent in $(t,1]$ where $t>0$ but not uniform convergent in $[0,1]$?
Please help, it is given in many books, but I find it uniform convergent throughout $[0,1]$.
I used weierstrass M test to show that mod$\frac{x}{1+n^2x}$ < $\frac{x}{n^2x}= \frac{1}{n^2}$. Now since $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent hence it is uniform convergent in $[0,1]$

Comment: Please include your thoughts and _how_ you obtain that it is uniformly convergent throughout $[0,1]$.

Comment: Using weierstras's M test, |f_n(x)|<=1/(n^2) and since summation (1/n^2) is convergent hence given series is uniform convergent in [0,1]. (Sorry for late reply difficult to write math :( will learn it today :))

Comment: I agree that the series is uniform convergent on $[0,1]$ by the Weierstrass M-test. What source says it is not?

Comment: Please stop edit your question over and over again. Edit it once to get the details you want to have in the question are in place. You have a preview, so that cannot be impossible...

Comment: Obviously, $\frac{x}{1+n^2x}$ should read $\frac{x}{1+n^2x^2}$.

Comment: @mickup it is a question in my university book. plz see the image http://h73i.imgup.net/IMG_2016017598.jpg

Comment: @mickup sorry guys will take care of all your suggestions. Mistake from the new entry :)